# Graphael line chart

Tags: javascript, raphael, linechart

Is there a good tutorial for Graphael (special line charts), I currently trying to implement such a graph with grafael http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=line-time-series&theme=default unfortunately there is no documentation.

Answer (score 39):

A useful resource has been Kenny Shen's GitHub repository where he has begun writing up both documentation and examples for gRaphael.

https://github.com/qoelet/g.raphael

As an example check out the line chart documentation [here](https://github.com/qoelet/g.raphael/blob/master/docs/line.md)

Comment: Shen no longer has a public github repo.

Comment: FYI, it's now at https://github.com/qoelet/g.raphael

Answer (score 3):

The best example of a Raphael linechart must be this one: http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html, from the source code you can get a lot of information on how they work and how they can be configured.

As far as I know there is no official documentation on this (yet?).

Comment: I have created my line chart now. I have only one problem, how will the line, which I'll go over, placed in the foreground?

There is a command insertBefore, but I could not use it properly.

Answer (score 3):

To change the stacking of the lines, use the toFront and toBack functions.

```
linechart.lines[index].toFront();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out RaphAlytics since it gives you quite a few options you can customize as well as the freedom to use multiple lines in the same graph and textual labels (which, unfortunately, gRaphael does not)

Check it out over here: https://github.com/tataencu/raphalytics

Answer (score 0):

For line charts here is good article: https://www.exratione.com/2011/10/a-few-tips-for-graphael-line-charts/